# Having Google Chrome Developer Tools open on Android Device

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

First up, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but it's the best I could think of.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the Google Chrome Developer Tools open on my Android device while I'm working on my Windows computer, as opposed to having it open in the same window as the browser. Something that would solve this would be using one of those screen extension apps, but I am not able to use these as I don't have any admin rights on the computer (school computer :/) so I can't install anything. Am I a bit too wishful in hoping that Google has something built in that I could use?

Edit: what i want is the developer tools open on my phone, while the web page I am debugging is open on my main computer, instead of having the developer tools pinned to the side of the web page. I am not debugging android apps, but web pages running in a browser on the computer. Thank you

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is remote debugging tools for chrome, check the official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) by facebook will do this although as you don't state what exactly you would like to see in the window I can't say if it will do what you need.

Comment: What I mean is the devtools window will be on the screen of the android device while the web page is open on my computer. I will edit the question. Thank you anyway